# Using Vaadin in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, vaadin

I have just installed the **Vaadin** plugin for **NetBeans**. I don't even know what to start with it, but I would love to know, how to get my head around it!

Can anyone help me out?

Just simple little programs or even just starting up my first program(Java).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at a Vaadin plugin tutorial:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/VaadinPlugin1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

The Netbeans and Vaadin websites do not maintain their tutorials for the latest versions of Netbeans and Vaadin, and are useless.  For example, the plugins are no longer installed in the way they currently describe and there are no complete and simple working examples of how to use a database with Vaadin.

For those who are struggling with the *current* method of installing the Vaadin plugin with NetBeans 8, the best way that I could find is to:

1. Start Netbeans (the Java EE version).
2. Go to Tools > Plugins > Installed
3. Look for Vaadin at the bottom of the list.  It will be there but will be unactivated.  Click the checkbox and activate/install it.

Unfortunately, even though I got the Vaadin plugin installed, I could find no tutorial that provided a clear explanation of how to use Netbeans 8 and Vaadin to create a simple Vaadin project that can read and write a record to a mysqli database.